# Specific currency exchange rates with Open Exchange Rates (lucr)

Tags: r, currency, rate

I initially used get.FX to retrieve exchange rates in R, but it is limited to 180 data points. My analysis requires a greater data base.

I found the package lucr which downloads data from open exchange rates - My issue is that I can not find a way to download one specific exchange rate from a certain period (e.g.EUR/USD for the last 365 days). Instead, if I request data for a certain period, I get the exchange rates from all currencies:

dt <- seq(as.Date(start0),by='days',length= 365)
USD <- historic_currency(dates = dt , currency="USD", key="...")

Delivers all USD exchange rates for the period dt. How can I retrieve one exchange rate for a certain period with lucr or another package?

Comment: In the documentation, it says that requesting specific symbols is currently only available for clients on the Developer, Enterprise and Unlimited plans, so I guess you can't except with one of these plans. See here: https://docs.openexchangerates.org/docs/historical-json